# Как программно подключить сетевой диск? VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Есть ли в .NET средства для того чтобы, в Windows если не подключен сетевой каталог, подключить его на определенную букву локального диска?

Comment: Посмотрите функции WNetAddConnection2/WNetAddConnection3

Comment: Насколько вижу это Win32API а не .NET

Comment: Думаете .NET не будет их в итоге использовать и тем самым в нем будет своя реализация? Сомневаюсь. Если не нравится WinAPI можете смело через .NET запускать net use с нужными параметрами.